# Can I put breakpoints on all occurences of some phrase in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, ide, breakpoints

Is there a way to after finding on occurences of some phrase in Java code in Eclipse (found ~100 matches in tens of files) to put a breakpoint on each of them?

The phrase I am looking for is a specific method called on specific instance of a class. It's a method from external jar so I cannot put a breakpoint inside it.

Comment: Depends on what the phrase is. If it's a method invocation you can break on method entry.  You need to provide more detail on what you are trying to do.

Comment: It's a method invocation, yes, but a method of external library.

Comment: Please help us to help you, don't make us pry out the details one question at a time. Show an example and tell us exactly what external library you are using.